# How to apply a .css file to the following PHP code:

Tags: php, html, redirect

Is there a way to add a css file to the following php code:

```
<?php            
   echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";   
?>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're outputting plain HTML in PHP . . .

Comment: I don't see what's wrong about it. It's a PHP code that redirects the link to terminate a session. And, I just wanted to style the link. Don't post if you don't understand!

Comment: Ack, typed that first comment too fast (whould have been why, not what) . . . As in, why are you outputting plain HTML in PHP?  The general suggestion being that if it's just HTML, no need to echo it in PHP, write it as HTML - cleaner and easier to maintain.  Obviously, others have answered the style questions, whether you do it inline, by assigning a selector and/or a style sheet, whether it's inline or externally sourced.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php  
      echo '<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
      echo "<a id='logout' href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";   
 ?>
```

in stylesheet.css:

```
#logout{color:green;font-size:.7em;border:1px solid black;}
```

Same way you would add it if it were html.

Comment: I tried your answer but the logout link doesn't take the style at all.

Comment: You would have to style it first. You can't just assume attaching a stylesheet will fix things. I'll update with an example of how things should look.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually context switch within PHP. Consider the following

```
<style type="text/css">
  a {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<?php  
  echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [inline CSS](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/inline.php), e.g.:

```
<p style="background: blue; color: white;">A new background and font color with inline CSS</p>
```